# Changing app name broke ability to run tests in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After I changed the product name for my app, I could still run the app in the simulator, but when I try to run tests, I get this error:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/stefankendall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-fcxmoirjyqcvalgdndrznrmnvtdw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OldAppName.app/ProjectRootDirectory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is the test action still trying to read from the old app name, even though I've changed the Product Name build property and xcode no longer builds to that location?

Comment: Your tests are a second target/product in your Xcode project, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to change the "bundle loader" property of your unit test target.

Check the other properties of both the test and the app for the "OldAppName" by typing it in the search field on the "Build Settings" page for both targets.

Here is a screen shot to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: @Xcoder I've added a screenshot. Could you elaborate on your request for elaboration?

Comment: This makes it easier thanks, but I figured out another way. Somehow my target got changed. THX anyway! Liked

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the answer. For me the problem was that after changing the app product name the Host Application could not be found anymore. I had to set it again in Test Target -> General and then needed to add $(TEST_HOST) manually for Bundle Loader in Build Settings because this field was empty too.

Answer (score 1):

How you changed your appname? from the Project navigation pane? or from the build settings packaging -> product name of the target ?However i also want to tell that second way is ideal way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have to change the name of the folder in which your project is stored to your new name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the product name to previous one. Build the project. Now update the product name to newer one. This works for me.